# BottomSheetFlatList doesn't scroll

Tags: react-native, expo, bottom-sheet

BottomSheetFlatList is a component of a react-native package "React Native Bottom Sheet".

In snack expo, I was trying out the following example https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/components/bottomsheetflatlist

I just copy-pasted the example code, removed Typescript syntax and everything renders as it should, yet contents inside the container refused to scroll up or down at all.

So why it doesn't scroll?